# Secondary hdd with swap partition: spindown?

Tags: hard-drive, swap

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a laptop. I have a small, 120GB SSD drive, and a secondary 1TB HDD.

Today I made Linux use a swap partition that is located on that second drive. After testing things out (opening LOTS of chrome tabs) and checking if the swap partition is used (it is), I noticed, that the drive in question doesn't spindown after some amount of time like it used to.

Battery life on my laptop is a huge deal to me, because I often have to work while traveling, with no way to recharge. Is there a way to force Linux out of using swap partition, and turn the second hdd off? Is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To force Linux not use the swap, run `sudo swapoff -a`

As for turning off the disk, you can do that through the included "Disks" application. See screenshot. (The option is grayed out *for me* as it is my system drive)

[image]

Comment: Any ideas on making Ubuntu do it automagically? :)

Comment: @BłażejMichalik - Automatically when what happens?

Comment: After a set amount of time, or whatever it is by default when there is no swap on it.

Comment: @BłażejMichalik You could look into the `tlp` package. Once installed, it sets up various power-saving optimizations automatically. It's quite "set-it-and-forget-it"; once it's installed, you don't need to manually do anything to make it work. Spinning down hard drives when they are idle is not enabled by default, but it can be enabled by editing the `DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_AC` and `DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_BAT` values in the `/etc/default/tlp` configuration file. More information here: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html

More generally http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html

Comment: @NickWeinberg - I would post that as an answer.

Comment: @NickWeinberg You should post it as an answer. ;)

Comment: I didn't think it was good enough to be an "official" answer, but ok, ok, I'll post it.

Comment: @NickWeinberg It adds information to the topic. Also, I didn't knew that `tlp` existed, so kudos to you.

Answer (score 2):

You could look into the `tlp` package (`sudo apt install tlp` will install it). Once installed, it sets up various power-saving optimizations for laptops automatically. It's quite "set-it-and-forget-it"; 
once it's installed, you don't need to manually do anything to make it work.

Spinning down hard drives when they are idle is a feature supported by tlp; **however,** it is not enabled by default. It 
can be enabled by editing the `DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_AC` and `DISK_SPINDOWN_TIMEOUT_ON_BAT` values in the `/etc/default/tlp` configuration file (the values indicate the number of seconds before the drive spins-down to save power; by default they are `0`, indicating no spin-down).

More information about manually configuring tlp: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/docs/tlp-configuration.html

More general information about tlp: http://linrunner.de/en/tlp/tlp.html